# Problema JavaFX en Eclipse con SceneBuilder

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

Estoy usando el modelo vista-controlador y a la hora de crear el controller mediante eclipse, no me genera los metodos en mi controlador. Os adjunto unas capturas de pantalla para que veais:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puede hacer es en el scene builder ir a la pestaña de "view" y elige la ultima opción "Show Sample Controller Skeleton" copea y pega en el controller